# How to test stenciljs nested components

Tags: javascript, testing, stenciljs

I have a stenciljs component embedded inside another stenciljs component

```
<parent-component>
  <child-component attrz="x">
  </child-component>
</parent-component>
```

The child-component is only rendered when the parent-component receives a hover event with an attribute 'attrz' set programmatically.  I set up the component in either spec.js or e2e.js and issue a hover event and then wait for changes.

e.g.:

```
  const page = await newE2EPage();
  await page.setContent(`<parent-component></parent-component>`);
  const el = await page.find('parent-component');
  await el.hover();
  await page.waitForChanges();
```

However, I cannot see this attribute in either spec.js or e2e.js tests.  Also it seems that neither spec.js nor e2e.js actually renders the child-component.

So my question is there any way I can test child components in stenciljs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access properties through the `getProperty()` function of E2EElement. So assuming that the rest of your test looks something like:

```
const child = await page.find('child-component');
```

You can test the 'attrz' property using:

```
expect(await child.getProperty('attrz')).toEqual('x');
```

You do not need the use reflect-to-attr in components to test properties.

Comment: Tested it and it works as you said.  Thank you.  Marked answer as correct.

Comment: as in StencilJS docs (https://stenciljs.com/docs/end-to-end-testing) the getProperty method is async, keep this in mind ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is also possible to test using `newSpecPage` on unit tests.

```
const child = page.root.querySelector('child-component');
```

Now just reference the `attrz` property value directly on the child:

```
expect(child.attrz).toEqual('x');
```